# How to specify the path when using @JSImport in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I have:

```
$ ls -last /home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar/jsgen/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
40 -rw-r--r-- 1 brandon brandon 37045 Jul 25  2016 /home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar/jsgen/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

and

```
@JSImport("node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "jQuery")
```

Yet when I run bundler I get the following error:

```
[error] ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' in '/home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar/jsgen/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main'
[error]     at factoryCallback (/home/brandon/workspace/ced2ar/jsgen/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:269:40)
```

I also tried just using the filename `bootstrap.min.js` for `@JSImport`. (Note: I figure that once I resolve this, I still have the issue of dealing with monkey patching, since that seems to be what bootstrap is doing to JQuery.)

Comment: You should be able to just write `"bootstrap.min.js"` in `@JSImport`. It should be the job of the bundler to resolve that name inside the Node.js modules.

Comment: I'm using sjs bundler 0.9.0; my build.sbt is here (if relevant I'll add the important bits to the question): https://gist.github.com/bbarker/7ba6f1f1e92066343be6d2135a182319 - I've tried a variety of options with `@JSImport` as well as trying to load `jquery.slim.min.js` instead, always with the same result. If that still doesn't elucidate the issue I'll try to put together a minimal example.

Comment: This worked: `@JSImport("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")` - thanks @dispalt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `node_modules` part in your path:

```
@JSImport("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "jQuery")
```

Be sure also that this file is CommonJS compatible.